# How long of a life is long enough?

Tags: dont-starve

Specifically, how long do I need to survive to get enough xp to unlock all the characters, and any other XP based unlocks?

I've got a camp set up such that I can basically go as long as I care to before I off myself to try one of the other characters.  I'm only on my second "life" though, so I don't have any idea what the XP scale is.

Is 35 days enough to unlock everything, or do I need to keep merrily farming my way into the future, before stepping off the abyss and starting it all up again with someone new?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You gain 20XP per day survived, regardless of how many days have passed. This means that now, to unlock every character up to Wigfrid it takes **96 days**. The detailed XP requirements for each character are the following:

- **Wilson**: starting character;
- **Willow**: 160XP;
- **Wolfgang**: 320XP;
- **Wendy**: 640XP;
- **WX-78**: 960XP;
- **Wickerbottom**: 1280XP;
- **Woodie** 1600 XP;
- **Wigfrid** 1920 XP (Reign of Giants exclusive).

At the moment of this update there are also three additional characters, but they're not unlocked with the experience points: two by playing the [Adventure Mode](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Adventure_Mode), and the other one is unlocked by performing special actions in-game (only if you have the Reign of Giants expansion).

Comment: Updated: You now earn a flat rate of 20XP per day, and the XP requirements have been lowered a bit. This is to help people who keep dying early, else they'd be at a disadvantage.

Comment: @Flater thanks, I'll check the new informations and update the answer

Comment: Two questions: (1) Do you have to do the 80 days with Wilson, or can you do it with any character?  (2) Do you have to do the 80 days at the default settings, or can you do it with different settings (e.g. only summer, only day, different amounts of items, etc.)?

Comment: @Kyralessa (1) Any character will do, you get 20 XP per day, no matter who you choose. (2) It should be indipendent from the initial settings

Comment: Do you have to have 1 game that lasts 80 days, or could you play 80 games where you survive 1 day? (or say, 20 games of 4 days?)

Comment: @Konerak it's 20 XP per day survived, no matter the number of consecutive days survived. So yes, you can play 80 1-day games