# How is XP calculated in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

When you die in Don't Starve, an XP bar appears, telling you the progress to unlocking the next character.

How is this calculated? Is there a set amount of XP you get for each day you survive, or does it increase over time? Do you get XP for other actions, like killing monsters, crafting more complicated items etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each day survived in Sandbox Mode gives exactly 20 XP. Adventure Mode does not reward any experience. To unlock all characters, you need to survive a cumulative 96 days. There is no experience reward for other actions such as killing or crafting.

Comment: This other answer says it's 80 days - has the requirement changed? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104176/how-long-of-a-life-is-long-enough?rq=1

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yes. New Character named Wigfried - 1920 XP

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness - "To unlock all characters, you need to survive a cumulative 96 days." I think there are two characters, Webber and Maxwell that need specific conditions to be unlocked.

Comment: @MarkRogers They are not included in this calculation